# Java generics for setting up the default AWS clients

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, generics, aws-sdk

I would like to be able to enforce different `httpClient` setups and `credentialsProvider` for all service clients created in our AWS backend. To do this I wanted to use Java Generics.

Whenever somone creates a new service client I would like to use it like this:

```
    S3Client s3client = setupAwsClient(S3Client.builder())
            .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();
```

My NOT compiling impl of `setupAwsClient` looks like this:

```
public <T extends AwsSyncClientBuilder<SdkSyncClientBuilder<...>, SdkClient> & BaseClientBuilder<S3ClientBuilder, SdkClient> T setupAwsClient(T client) {

    return client
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .httpClient(awsBaseClient);
}
```

The problem is that there are so many interfaces I have to specify that the functions looks like a mess.

My question is: What would be the clean way to enforce some setup among all service clients in the AWS SDK? Is generics a good solution or are there better ways?

UPDATE:

```
public <T extends AwsSyncClientBuilder<?,?> & AwsClientBuilder<?, ?>> T setup(T clientBuilder) {

}
```

Trying this is not working either. Even that `AwsClientBuilder` provides `credentialsProvider` and `AwsSyncClientBuilder` provides `httpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

[AwsSyncClientBuilder](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsSyncClientBuilder.java#L32) take it self or any of it's subtypes as a type params, but [SdkSyncClientBuilder](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-opensdk/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/opensdk/protect/client/SdkSyncClientBuilder.java#L60) is not a subtype of AwsSyncClientBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of what you're looking for?

```
public <T extends AwsSyncClientBuilder<?, ?>> T setup(T clientBuilder) {
  /* Do stuff to client */
  return clientBuilder;
}
```

Or if you want the setup method to call build:

```
public <C, T extends AwsSyncClientBuilder<?, C>> C setup(T clientBuilder) {
  /* Do stuff to client */
  return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: this does not provide the credentialsProvider, only the httpClient

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-thinking this, and letting the complexity of the AWS SDK filter into your application code.

First up, do you really need the async clients? What benefit would they provide you versus combining a synchronous client and a threadpool?

Second, what are you really trying to configure? It looks like you want to let the calling code configure the region but not the credentials provider? Is there anything else that you want to allow or control?

The solution that I'd use would be a simple factory method that takes a configuration object that you define:

```
public static <T> T createClient(Class<T> clientKlass, MyConfigObject config)
```

So, based on your example you might call like this:

```
MyConfigObject config = new MyConfigObject().withRegion(Region.EU_WEST_1)
S3Client s3Client = createClient(S3Client.class, config)
```

Inside the `createClient()` method I would probably use a simple if-else chain to pick the appropriate builder:

```
if (clientKlass == S3Client.class) {
    S3ClientBuilder builder = S3Client.builder();
    applyConfig(builder, config);
    return builder.build();
}
```

If you don't like if-else chains, you could use reflection to invoke the `builder()` method on the passed client class (and the `build()` method on the result).

The `applyConfig()` method relies on all clients deriving from `AwsClientBuilder`, which provides methods for common configuration:

```
private static void applyConfig(AwsClientBuilder builder, MyConfiguration config) {
    if (config.getRegion() != null) {
        builder.region(config.getRegion());
    }
    builder.credentialsProvider(standardCredentials);
}
```

Comment: Im not using the async clients? The other thing I want to control is the httpClient used since I must setup a proxy on this for all service clients to work.

Comment: And the httpClient Im not able to set in your applyConfig.
Another problem is that I have to know all things a user might what to configure and put that in the MyConfiguration. I do know what needs to be set (the 2 fields in the example), however I dont know all the fields that someone might want to set.

I dont really like your solution for the reasons stated here.

Comment: In practice there are very few things that a user will configure. And most of those will be configured at the application level.

Comment: As for you not liking this solution. I'm OK with that. I think, however, you should at least pay attention to using abstraction in your favor.